# Cannot convert value of type 'GameScene' to expected argument type 'UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to show AdMob interstitial ads in gamescene Xcode. When I try to load them using the google tutorial it says

> Error - Cannot convert value of type 'GameScene' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'.

Here is the code

```
if self.interstitial.isReady {
        self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        }
    else{
        print("failed to load")
    }
```

I tried to do - as UIViewController -  after the self but it still did not work.

Comment: Is the `self` in the code snippet of the type `GameScene`? If `GameScene` doesn't subclass UIViewController, you should maybe move this piece of code to another class that does (something that can talk to the `GameScene`).

Comment: If this is the tutorial you're referring to: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial, take note of the text "Here's an example of how to do this in one of the action methods in a UIViewController".

Answer (score -1):

It is working for me in GameScene :

```
if interstitial != nil {
    interstitial!.present(fromRootViewController: self.view?.window?.rootViewController)
} else {
    print("Ad wasn't ready")
}
```